# The problem of solve the limit separately

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

We consider limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sqrt[n]{n}+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=\infty$$
But if we take the limit separately, for example, develop first the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$, we get $e^3$.
I understand all the steps of the right solution but don't understand the reason very profoundly. In the resolution, the Taylor Polynomial of $e^{x}$ of order 1. I know the $e^x=1+x+o(x)$, but I don't argue another strong reason why we don't use the other term.
I want to understand this topic more deeply. Thank you!

Comment: If $a_n\to1$, we generally don't have $\lim(a_n+b_n)^n=\lim(1+b_n)^n$ (even if $b_n\to0$).  (E.g. $a_n=1+1/n,b_n=1/n$. ) Can you please edit your post to include the solution you were given, and specify more precisely what troubles you?

Comment: Where does $e^3$ come from?

Comment: You need to follow limit laws, you cannot arbitrary move limit around.

Comment: Yeah i know maybe i am making thinks more complicated of necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{\log n}n}=1+\frac{\log n}n+o\left(\frac{\log n}n\right)$$

therefore

$$\left(\sqrt[n]{n}+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{\log n}n+o\left(\frac{\log n}n\right)+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n$$

and the $\frac{\log n}n$ causes the divergence to infinity, indeed by Bernoulli's inequality

$$\left(1+\frac{\log n}n+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{3+\log n}n\right)^n\ge 4+\log n \to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\left(1+\frac{3}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right)^n\ge \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n=\infty
$$